A particular application of Rouche's theorem
Given $r\in (0,1)$ I have to show that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$\Sigma_{n=0}^N\frac{z^n}{n!}=e$$
has a unique solution in $D(1,r)$.
I was trying to apply Rouche to this case where the two functions are $e^z$ and the given function as above. Now to apply the theorem I will have to estimate the tail of the series $e^z$ in the given disc. How should I proceed after this? Is there any other function I can apply Rouche's theorem to?
Thanks in advance.

If $f_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N z^n/n!$, in order to use Rouché's theorem
you'll probably want to have $|\exp(z) - f_N(z)| < |\exp(z) - e|$ on the circle $|z-1| = r$. The minimum of the right side on the circle is some positive number, let's call it $\varepsilon$
(you could try to estimate it, but the actual value doesn't really matter for this question).   Now you want to show that for sufficiently large $N$, $\left| \exp(z) - f_N(z) \right| < \varepsilon$ on the circle. Again, detailed estimates are not needed if you know that $\exp$ is an entire function, and Taylor series of an entire function converge to that function uniformly on compact sets.
